# Convert a character vector into a character string with quotes and commas

Tags: r, string

After a thorough search, I am still stuck with this (rather small but still annoying) problem:

I have a character vector:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

I would like to get a character string exactly of the form:

```
"a", "b", "c"
```

I have tried countless combinations of `cat()` and `paste()` functions, with combinations of `sep` and `collapse`, using `\"...` but cannot make it to work.

Comment: Maybe `paste("\"", paste(x, collapse = "\", \""), "\"", sep = "")`?

Comment: `sub('.*\\((.*)\\).*', '\\1', capture.output(dput(x)))`, maybe. Or `paste0('"', x, '"', collapse = ', ')`.

Comment: I have found something that works:

`cat("\"",paste(x, collapse = "\", \""),"\"",sep = "")`

I post it here for those who could be interested...

@Psidom, @alistaire: thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You want a string with quotes inside? Here you go:

```
> x <- c("a", "b", "c")
> s <- paste0('"', paste(x, collapse='", "'), '"')
> print(s, quote=F)
[1] "a", "b", "c"
```